# Ideal number of spritesheets for LWJGL/OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, sprite-sheet

I am making a game using LWJGL, and so far I decided to have 5 or 6 sprite sheets. It is like one for the blocks, one for the items, objects, etc. By doing that, I have sprite sheets with sprites that are closely related, and normally have the same size (in the case of blocks and items). But is this the better way? Or should I just throw everything on a single sprite sheet, with no organization whatsoever?

If I am doing it the right way, there is also another problem. For example, when you are in the map, I need to draw the blocks. But over the blocks, there can be electrical wires and other stuff - that are in a separated sprite sheet. This information, however, is stored in the same array. So normally I just iterate over it once, and each time, draw the block, and then the wire over it - switching sprite sheets twice each iteration. But I thought it might take some time to switch these, so maybe it would be more interesting to run the thing twice, first draw all the blocks, and then iterate again to draw the wires? To change the textures, I am using the SlickUtil Texture class, which has a bind method - really easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "ideal"; there are simply the factors that matter for your needs.

Remember the reason why you use sprite sheets at all: because switching textures is too expensive to do per-object when dealing with 2D rendering. So as long as you're not switching textures for each sprite you render, you'll already be ahead of the game performance-wise.

The other considerations you need to take into account are:

- Minimum user hardware specifications. Specifically, what is the minimum size of `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` you want your code to work on? The larger your sprite sheets get, the greater your hardware requirements, since a single sprite sheet must be a texture.

  This value is hardware-dependent, but there are some general requirements. OpenGL 3.3 requires 1024 at a minimum; pretty much every piece of GL 3.3 hardware gives 4096. OpenGL 4.3 requires a massive 16384, which is approaching the theoretical limits of floating-point texture coordinate capacity (assuming you want at least 8 bits of sub-pixel texture coordinate precision).

  GL 2.1 has a minimum requirement of 64, but any *actual* 2.1 hardware people will have will offer between 512 and 2048. So pick your sprite sheet size based on this.
- What you're rendering. You want to be able to render as much as possible from one sprite sheet. What you want to avoid is *frequent* texture switches. If your world is divided into layers, if you can fit your sprites for each layer onto their own sheet, you're doing fine. No hardware is going to choke on 20 texture changes; it's tens of thousands that are the problem.

  The main thing is to render everything that uses a sheet all at once. Not necessarily in the same render call; you can switch meshes and shader uniforms/fixed-function state. But you shouldn't switch sheets between these renders until you've rendered everything needed for that sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will keep using a few sprite sheets then, and just change the rendering of the map so that first all blocks are drawn and then the wires.